# Adding default reviewers to Github repository

Tags: github

I followed the instructions here https://help.github.com/articles/about-codeowners/ but it doesn't seem to work. I even added the `CODEOWNERS` file at both the `root` and `.github` directory. The reviewers specified in the `CODEOWNERS` file are not selected automatically when a pull request is created. See screenshots below. Onyone who has set this up, could you point to where the problem is. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 18):

You need to be sure that your base branch has:

- the 'Protect this branch' flag activated
- the 'Require pull request reviews before merging' flag activated
- the 'Require review from Code Owners' flag activated

Then in the CODEOWNERS file, located either in the root of the repo or in the .github subfolder, you need to have either a user described with '@user', a user described with his email like 'user@domain.com', or a team described with '@org/teamname'.

You will need also to be sure that:

- your contributors (users and teams) have for each of them the 'write' access to the repo
- the team is not a 'secret' team, only the 'visible' teams would be taken into account

Answer (score 10):

Double-check the [CODEOWNERS file syntax](https://help.github.com/articles/about-codeowners/#codeowners-syntax)

> The pattern is followed by one or more GitHub usernames or team names using the standard `@username` or `@org/team-name` format.

(I don't see @ in your case)

> You can also refer to a user by an email address that has been added to their GitHub account, for instance user@example.com.

If the syntax is correct, then you can [contact GitHub support](https://github.com/contact) to have them investigate.

---

The [OP Pratheep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983439/pratheep) actually find this is working:

> You need the `@` and referring to my last screenshot above, you don't see the reviewers in the list when creating the PR.
>   But **once the PR is created, then you will see the reviewers in the list**.
>
> I believe it was by design not to show. Because if you show the reviewers in that list before the PR is created, the names can be removed.
>   This way no one can create a PR without notifying the codeowners/default reviewers.

Comment: I did try with with `@` but it didn't seem to work so it removed it. BUT in fact it works! So you need the `@` and referring to my last screenshot above, you don't see the reviewers in the list when creating the PR but once the PR is created then you will see the reviewers in the list.

Comment: @Pratheep OK, so it does work, but in a "degraded" way (the PR needs to be fully created)

Comment: I believe it was by design not to show. Because if you show the reviewers in that list before the PR is created, the names can be removed. This way no one can create a PR without notifying the codeowners/default reviewers

Comment: @Pratheep Got it. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

The CODEOWNERS file should be in the `.github` folder per the [Codeowners location documentation](https://docs.github.com/es/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners#codeowners-file-location).